# Mysterious color showing up on tab hover

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui

In my site's design, I am using jQuery UI tabs, and I would like to change a dark green color that shows up when I hover over the tabs. However, I cannot find this color anywhere in the CSS or override it, and the Chrome developer tools do not show any such color matched to the tabs. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uy4Jz/1/

I feel like this CSS should be able to override it but that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-state-active { 
    background: transparent url(images/uiTabsArrow.png) no-repeat bottom center; 
    border: none; 
    color: #000;
}
```

How should I go about changing this color or overriding it with a different color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from this declaration in your CSS:

```
.ui-state-hover a,
.ui-state-hover a:hover,
.ui-state-hover a:link,
.ui-state-hover a:visited {
    color: #205225;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Probably best to update all instances of

```
color: #205225;
```

To the appropriate hex color you're after.

Comment: Happy to help! It might be worth your time to look at the Firebug add-on (other browsers have similar tools) and specifically at the "Inspect Element" feature, which shows you the CSS stack applied :} 15 second video: https://vimeo.com/61942699

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite this in your CSS with your desired color

```
.ui-state-hover a, 
.ui-state-hover a:hover, 
.ui-state-hover a:link, 
.ui-state-hover a:visited{
    color: #205225; /*change this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about "Blog", "About Me" and "Projects", target the `a` within the `li` list and style its hover psuedo element

```
#tabs ul li a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```